# Getting error while on PeerConnection.IceServer builder error: cannot find symbol method builder(String)

Tags: android, webrtc, apprtc, webrtc-android

I am implementing Webrtc in android . while implementing I am getting this error

[tap here to the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjclC.png)

```
List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
PeerConnection.IceServer.Builder iceServerBuilder = PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:x.ga");
iceServerBuilder.setTlsCertPolicy(PeerConnection.TlsCertPolicy.TLS_CERT_POLICY_INSECURE_NO_CHECK); //this does the magic.

PeerConnection.IceServer stunServer =  iceServerBuilder.createIceServer();

PeerConnection.IceServer turnServer =
        PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("turn:x.ga?transport=udp")
                .setUsername("user7")
                .setPassword("abc123456")
                .createIceServer();
```

getting an error in the .builder method you can also check on the image

I am referencing from this demo. This demo is working fine not getting .builder issue.

Please, anybody, know how to resolve this?

Comment: Please describe your problem correctly, enter the code snippet where you can understand the problem and the reported error. Your question is incomplete and so it is not possible to provide a solution.

Comment: alright please check now @RenanBarbosa